# Custom Swipe Function Look

Tags: ios, swift

How would I go about creating a custom Swipe function that looks like this? Is this able to be done with the built in functions or would this need to be custom? Thanks!
[image]

Comment: If you mean you want the cell to just look like that, from scratch, and for the "front" part to be draggable sideways, then yes, that's something you would have to build yourself. A cell containing a horizontal scroll view might be in order.

Answer (score 0):

## Customizing swipe actions

It appears that you are talking about [tableView(*:trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt:)*](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/2902367-tableview) or [tableView(:leadingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/2902366-tableview)

Either of those two (or both) functions should be added to the Controller of desired Table View.

You can also customize them inside as follows:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {

        let someAction = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: "Some Action") { (action, sourceView, completionHandler) in
            // Do something you want
        }
}
```

You can also add custom images to those actions and customize background color as follows:

```
someAction.image = UIImage(named: "imageName")
someAction.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 200.0/255.0, green: 100.0/255.0, blue: 100.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
```

Here is a sample result of tableView(_:trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt:) implementation:

[image]

## Customizing TableViewCell

You can create custom Table View Cell in numerous ways, one way may be to do it both from your Storyboard and from your code

#### Storyboard

Firstly, you can customize your cell in the Attributes inspector of your storyboard

[image]

From there you can set background color, style, etc.

Then I you can add a View to the Content View. You can also edit it using Attributes inspector setting its background etc.

[image]

One thing that I also prefer doing in Storyboard is Clipping it to bounds in Attributes inspector and then setting the Corner Radius in the Identity inspector. This will create a custom View with rounded corners. You can do it from code too

[image]

#### Code

Now you will need to create custom .swift file that inherits from UITableViewCell and assign it to your cell in Identity inspector

[image]

Then put custom objects to your cell and connect your Storyboard with .swift file by Ctrl+Drag to yield the following connection

[image]

Your .swift file should contain Outlets/Actions for further customization

#### Result

In my case I have added 2 ImageViews and a Label to obtain following result:

[image]

#### Editing Swipe Actions' Appearance

Apparently, swipe actions are pretty rigid in terms of customization, you cannot edit them. One way around may be detecting swipe gesture and creating your own logic for your view or you can use [SwipeCellKit](https://github.com/SwipeCellKit/SwipeCellKit) to customize this actions

Comment: Hi, this is how you add a normal Swipe Action but I am wondering how you create a swipe action with this custom look...

Comment: hi, could you please be more specific on how the swipe action should be custom?

Comment: As in the corner mask that masks the cell content and slide background.

Comment: I have updated the answer with description on how you edit Table View Cell, hope it helps

Comment: The sliding section is not masked in this answer.